# why im getting FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: error

Tags: python, module, pycharm, operating-system, file-not-found

Here I'm trying to rename the files bbut idont know what is wrong i'm getting **FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Screenshot (72).png' -> '72-Screenshot.png' plz anyone show me the path to resolve this error**

```
import os
for i in os.listdir('Experiment'):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(i)
    f_name, f_num = f_name.split('(')
    f_name = f_name.strip()
    f_num, f_useless = f_num.split(')')
    k = f'{f_num}-{f_name}{f_ext}'
    os.rename(i, k)
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYpdL.png[1]

Comment: The file with the name stored in `i` doesn't exist in the current working directory.

Comment: Without knowing the directory structure and example of contents it's difficult to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 

> [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Screenshot
> (72).png

- 

-----------> **remove the space form the <file_name>.png**
**Program :**

```
import os
path  = os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in filenames:
     os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace(' ', '-')))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is adding the 'Experiment/' directory before the *ith* file in that directory it should be like os.path.splitext('Experiment/' + i).

Instead what's happening is you're looking for the *ith* file in the python file directory instead of the 'Experiment' directory.

Same thing with the rename the 'Experiment' directory should be included before the i and the k as well.

Comment: Do you get the files you're trying to access when you type: print(os.listdir('Experiment/')), Also you need to add / after Experiments in os.listdir in the for loop.